# I am a US citizen with a US job that is sending me to work in Germany for 60 days - what visa do I need?

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, work, working-visas

As the title says, I'm a US citizen and I work for a US company. My company has a branch in Germany, and I'll transfer to that branch for 60 days next year. I'll do all the same work I do for the US company, still get paid by the US company, but I get to be face-to-face with my German colleagues.

I have no idea what visa I should apply for. When I look at the [German Missions in the United States site](https://www.germany.info/us-en/service/visa), I see two articles:

> A Schengen visa is required if you intend to stay in the Schengen area for up to 90 days within a 180 day period for business, visitor or tourist purposes.

and

> A residence visa is required if you intend to stay in Germany for more than 90 days for work or study or if you intend to move to Germany permanently.

but I'm trying to work in Germany for less than 90 days, so it looks like neither is applicable?

When I go to the [visa navigator page](https://visa.diplo.de/en/index.html#/vib), again it's mentioning the Schengen visa as:

> If you want to travel to Germany for a period of up to 90 days – for a visit, as a tourist, on business, or for medical treatment – you will need a Schengen visa.

but again no mention of work here, and when I click on the "Quick Check" it redirects me to here, which eventually asks if I have a binding job offer or no job offer, but again I won't have any German job at all, and I won't be seeking one, either.

I found [this similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47520/will-stay-less-than-90-days-in-germany-but-will-work-there-what-kind-of-visa-d), which is almost exactly what I'm looking for, but

1. The link there is broken,
2. The content seems to revolve around internships in Germany, which is a kind of work for a Germany institution, and
3. When I search the document filename (l6019022dstbai381815.pdf) from the broken link, all the associated content is about internships.

It seems like there needs to be some kind of work *permit* and not work *visa*, but it's not clear what the permit is, who needs to complete it (again, I won't be working for a Germany company while I'm there!) and what visa I should have to enter with the work permit.

Comment: I'd say that what you describe is precisely business purposes, and this qualifies as a Schengen visa.

Comment: I think my question is, concisely, whether remote work for the US company is allowed while I'm on the business/Schengen visa.

Comment: Note that while some people need one, as a US citizen, you don't actually need a visa to visit Germany for tourism or business purposes for less than 90 days. Now the big question is "is what you will do _business_ or _work_". Welcome to the wonderful grey area of immigration law.

Comment: Can you describe what your work is? Some activities are clearly deemed business. Others are clearly considered work. And in between...

Comment: @jcaron - I'm a software developer, so any "work" I would be doing would involve working directly on my laptop (not as likely) or connecting to the US office via VPN and working on a remote session. I don't do anything tangibile.

Comment: @Chuck What will you be doing over there? In other words, why do you need to go there to do your work? If you're meeting with your colleagues to discuss plans for version 22 of the-big-project or training them on the use of version 21, that's business. If you are explicitly outsourced to German customers, that's work, for instance. Also, is your company HR department not able to assist with this? Beyond paperwork, you'll need to sort out a place to live, surely they don't expect you to arrange all that (in a company that can afford to send you abroad for 2 months...).

Comment: @jcaron - really, it's pretty much as described in the list of expressly permitted "business" activities - I'm going to meet the German part of the company, to learn how they operate, to attend their meetings, to see their campus, etc. etc. When I'm not in meetings with them I'll keep doing the same work I would do here in the US, so I'll never be turning a wrench in Germany, will never speak to a German customer, etc. It's a kind of a cultural exchange program my employer is offering. They've contracted an "immigration specialist" firm that I've had bad experiences with at other employers.

Comment: Has your employer not advised you of anything?

Comment: @Chuck if anyone asks, just mention the training and meeting part, not the “same work as in the US” part. And don’t say “transfer”.

Comment: I would not use the word "work" at all. Your employer really should be providing more support in this matter, in my opinion.

Comment: "I'll keep doing the same work I would do here in the US, so I'll never be turning a wrench in Germany": writing software is an economic activity on a par with turning a wrench.  The provision of services is no different from the production of tangible goods as far as work visas are concerned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a US citizen, you don't need a visa if you stay less than 90 days out of 180 and perform "**business activities**". Which is not "**work**".

The list of activities allowed for Germany is listed [here](https://uk.diplo.de/uk-en/02/visa/professional-activities-not-classed-as-work/2447446).

Note that it says:

> the following lists are **not exhaustive** and are **subject to individual interpretation**. Both lists are meant as a guideline only and do not constitute legal advice. It is the responsibility of travellers to ensure that any activity conducted falls within the scope of permitted activities. If in doubt, you should take legal advice from an immigration lawyer or specialist

(emphasis mine)

The list provides both activities that are allowed and a few which aren't. If you're lucky you fall clearly in the allowed activities (such as training staff, negotiating contracts...). If you're unlucky you fall clearly in the activities not allowed (which will require a work visa). And if you're in between... Good luck!

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it's provided a list of activities that are expressly permitted under a business visa. Notable is the `In-company continuing education and training` section, which states, `Skilled workers employed abroad by an internationally operating group or company for the purpose of in-company continuing education and training in the German part of the group or company.` This is my situation exactly, thank you so much for the link.

Comment: @Chuck be careful.  "All the same work I do for the US company" is not "in-company continuing education and training," even if your presence there is to "be face-to-face with my German colleagues."  Some countries are strict about that; I don't know what Germany's attitude is.  Your company should get a formal opinion from a German lawyer specializing in employment immigration law.  You should consider taking your own legal advice from an independent lawyer, because if you are found to have violated German law it will be _you_ who is saddled with an adverse immigration history.

Comment: @Chuck another thing to think about: income taxation.  The money you earn for your work in Germany is likely taxable in Germany.  I don't know the details of German law but if there is any _de minimis_ exception, you still surely exceed the threshold by working there for two months.

Comment: @phoog - Yeah, after further consideration and discussion with my counterpart in Germany, he said essentially the same thing: I can get and receive *training*, but not *work*. If all I were doing is learning how the company operates, etc., then that would qualify, but probably my role will still be *working* in Germany. Probably I'll move forward with getting a work visa for me and I'm pushing the company to engage a German immigration lawyer to confirm the class of visa we need and to provide a form letter future employees can carry with them when they go through this program.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer nor I do have much knowledge about specific Schengen regulation, but...

From a general point of view, what you describe is a perfect example of *business purposes*, and thus it qualifies for a standard Schengen visa. It does not matter that you will be doing work for your US employer during your trip; anyway, arguably any *business* visa imples that you do work for your employer. Standard examples of business purposes are visiting a conference or negotiating with a business partner, but this is anyway your *work*, i.e. something that you do at a request of your employer and what you get paid for. In your case you are going to Germany to collaborate with your colleagues, which is still a perfect business reason for me. Presumably you employer will provide you with documents needed for the embassy so that the embassy will see that there is a business need.

A different case might be if you go to Germany out of your own will (e.g. your US employer is happy with you working remotely from anywhere on Earth, and you choose to spend two months in Germany, a digital nomad type of trip), this is at very least a shady area in modern visa regulations, — but if it is your employer requirement (and the employer will provide you with needed documents), then it is a business case.

Just two things that seem concerning to me.

First, I would not say that you "transfer" to the Germany branch. The word "transfer" may suggest that you will have a new contract with that branch and be paid by that branch, which is really not a business trip, but a full-scale work. However, you say that you'll be still paid by your US branch, so just say that you are going on a business trip to collaborate with your colleagues.

Second, unless you have a specific project to complete, 60 days might seem a bit excessive for just "meeting your colleagues and collaborating". Maybe the visa officer will not mind and a simple letter from your employer will be enough.

Finally, as an US citizen do you need a visa at all? (Although even if you don't need a visa for a business trip, you most probably still need a visa for work, so a distinction between business trip and work is still important.)

Once again, I'm answering from common sense, not from some specific experience, and hope that more knowledgeable users will give more specific answers.